# How to change the user-agent of chromium (google chrome) from the command line?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to write a question for a CTF (Cybersecurity Hacking Competition). Part of the question will include an XSS vulnerability where the user can "report" a URL. When the user reports a URL, I run chromium in headless mode to visit the URL.

I am currently using the following shell script (.sh) to make chromium visit the URL in headless mode (while hiding all output and running in the background).

```
chromium-browser --headless {url} > /dev/null &
```

I want the "flag", or what the user is trying to steal from the fake user, to be the browsers user agent.

I plan on running this question from an AWS EC2 server, so I do not believe I can change chromium's user agent by visiting some options in the browser. Is there a way I can do this from the console? Perhaps an option in `chromium-browser` or a config file that I can write to?

Edit: Should have mentioned that the system I am running on is Ubuntu 18.04.
Edit 2: An example of what the User-Agent should look like: `flag{u53r_4g3nt!!}`

Comment: You can use this switch to change user-agent: ``--user-agent="Your new user agent"`` when starting your Chromium. You should pass that argument to Chromium